# What is the noun that is modified by 'on the hop'?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

> A catches B on the hop.

What is the subject that is modified by 'on the hop'? A, catches, or B?

Comment: Ir certainly refers to either A or B, but it is ambiguous as to which one.

Comment: @BillJ: I don''t see any scope for ambiguity. It's ***B*** who is caught "on the hop" (when he's not expecting it), as you can tell by rephrasing to near-synonymous *A caught B **unawares***. Obviously A is aware of / expecting the impending capture, since he's the one actively causing it to happen. So ***on the hop / unawares*** are adjectivally modifying ***B***.

Comment: My question was not limited to either A or B–the verb 'catches' should be included for consideration like Astralbee's answer below.

Comment: @BEBYGONES Why do you believe that "catches" is a subject?

Comment: I missunderstood 'the subject' for a thing that is modified. It would have been better to use 'one' instead of  'subject'. I think 'on the hop' modifies the verb 'catches'.

Answer (score 3):

The entire idiom is "***caught** on the hop*" and means to be *unexpectedly found busy*. In your example, the entire idiom "caught on the hop" is present but broken up by the sentence structure. As your question is specifically what the words 'on the hop' acted on within that example, it is necessary to break it down.

I've always understood "*on the hop*" to mean '*busy*' or '*active*'. Likewise, 'hop' can mean *to move quickly* from one place to another. A similar phrase "on the hoof" means travelling or walking, but idiomatically has come to mean busy, active, working.

So, in your example, 'on the hop' is acting as an adjective, describing B and the state they were 'caught' (or found) in by A.

Comment: You(Astralbee) answered that 'on the hop' modifies the verb 'catches'. What made you edit the answer?

Comment: From [Collins:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/on-the-hop) *If you are caught on the hop, you are surprised by someone doing something when you were not expecting them to and so you are not prepared for it.* I'm not aware of any particular connection to "**busy**" - unless you extrapolate to *[while the "victim" was **occupied with something else*** (hence not paying attention to detect his impending "capture"), but I don't think that's inherently part of the idiom itself.

Comment: @BEBYGONES I edited it because I thought more about it and my original thoughts weren't quite right. "Caught on the hop" is an entire idiom in itself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "on the hop" means you are moving, active, busy. Consider the comparable "on the hoof" which has a particular idiomatic meaning, but at its root means that you are active, moving. But I agree that the entire idiom is "caught on the hop". The way it has been broken up in this example merits an explanation of what 'on the hop' would mean in isolation.

Comment: I provided a link defining the idiom that doesn't mention anything about "busy". And imho you could certainly be "caught on the hop" if you were sitting quietly at home reading a book at the time (or even just "meditating"). If you want to insist the idiom implies "busy", you should provide a link *in the answer text* to a definition supporting that position.

Comment: @FumbleFingers https://thesaurus.plus/related/busy/on_the_hop

Comment: The content of that linked page is obviously computer-generated (and highly suspect). It's not even *close* to a "dictionary definition".

Comment: busy: https://english.dict.naver.com/english-dictionary/#/entry/enen/2cbf5cb64c994246b3ae86872edfe9a9     , https://english.dict.naver.com/english-dictionary/#/entry/enen/2cbf5cb64c994246b3ae86872edfe9a9

Comment: @BEBYGONES the definitions you posted are filed under 'on the hop' but both say "**caught** on the hop" before defining it. In this context, 'caught' means 'found' and is a verb. Who is doing the 'catching'? In your example it is 'A'. Who is 'on the hop'? That would be 'B'. So there **must** be a separate definition for 'on the hop'. Even if it is 'unaware' or 'unprepared' and not 'busy', my answer stands that it describes B.